# Automapper Mapping Complex nested Objects

Tags: c#, automapper

I am currently facing an error whilst trying to map data objects as shown below;

```
Method 'get_Item' in type 'Proxy_System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[[InsureAfrika_API.Model.DataModel, InsureAfrika API, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]_28141317_' from assembly 'AutoMapper.Proxies, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=be96cd2c38ef1005' does not have an implementation.
```

Below are my data sources;
**QuoteSourceDto**

```
public string ResponseStatus { get; set; }
public IList<Data> Data { get; set; }
```

**DataClass**

```
public string Client { get; set; }
public IList<Extensions> Extensions { get; set; }
```

**Extensions Source Class**

```
public Decimal Limit { get; set; }
public Decimal Rate { get; set; }
```

My Destination Class; **QuoteDestinationModel**

```
public string ResponseStatus { get; set; }
public IList<DataModel> Data { get; set; }
```

**DataModel**

```
public string Client { get; set; }
public IList<ExtensionsModel> Extensions { get; set; }
```

**ExtensionModel Class**

```
public Decimal Limit { get; set; }
public Decimal Rate { get; set; }
```

Below is my mapper configuration;

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
   cfg.CreateMap<IList<Extensions>, IList<ExtensionsModel>>();
   cfg.CreateMap<IList<Data>, IList<DataModel>>();

   cfg.CreateMap<QuoteSourceDto, QuoteDestinationModel>()
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.Data, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Data))
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.ResponseStatus, opt => opt.Ignore());
})
```

My Data Source;

```
IList<Extensions> exts =new List<Extensions>
{
   new Extensions{Rate=1.34M,Limit=21400.00M};
}

IList<Data> dat = new List<Data>
{
  new Data{Client="Micael Angelus", Extensions =exts};
};

QuoteSourceDto dtos = new QuoteSourceDto
{
     ResponseStatus = "Success",
     Data = dat
};
```

Thus my Map function call is as shown below;

```
var _client = mapper.Map<QuoteSourceDto, QuoteDestinationModel>(dtos);
```

When I use type `List` it returns no error and no result just an empty list and when I use `IList` it returns the stated error above. All I want to do is map results to QuoteDestinationModel.

**EDIT**
I'm Using Automapper Version 9.0.0

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Lists-and-arrays.html

Comment: I've spent 3hrs debugging using their documentation and I still haven't figured out why I'm getting this error.

Comment: There are many examples available online. Try the tests in the AM repo.

Comment: That's not an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AutoMapper documentation states:

> *"AutoMapper only requires configuration of element types, not of any array or list type that might be used. "* ~ [Documentation](http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Lists-and-arrays.html)

What that means is that you don't have to (and you shouldn't) create mapping profiles between particular types of collections (using generic type parameter), like you did:

```cs
// Don't do that!
cfg.CreateMap<IList<Extensions>, IList<ExtensionsModel>>();
```

Instead, create mapping profiles between concrete types:

```cs
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<Extensions, ExtensionsModel>();
    cfg.CreateMap<Data, DataModel>();
    cfg.CreateMap<QuoteSourceDto, QuoteDestinationModel>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.ResponseStatus, opt => opt.Ignore());
});
```

and AutoMapper will create a collection for you. Types of source collections supported:

- `IEnumerable`
- `IEnumerable<T>`
- `ICollection`
- `ICollection<T>`
- `IList`
- `IList<T>`
- `List<T>`
- `Array`

Notice that I removed the configuration part telling AutoMapper how to map between `Data` members. As both - source and destination - models have the same name, which is just `Data`, AutoMapper will map them just fine without explicitly telling it how to do that. That is, if you previously create a map between `Data` and `DataModel` types in configuration.